# SQL script compatible SQL Server 2005

Tags: c#, unit-testing, sql-server-2005

I have an application and this will "install" some stored procedures into a local database.

I want to make a unit test to validate the stored procedures so that the will be valid from SQL Server 2005 and up.

Is there a way to do this with / without SQL Server?

Comment: How do you mean unit-test the stored procedure? What do you expect the tests to give you?

Comment: The only way to validate them is to install them on SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 1):

The Data Dude (Gert Drapers) describes how to use the built-in SQL Server T-SQL parser in your application here:

- [Getting to the Crown Jewels](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gertd/archive/2008/08/21/getting-to-the-crown-jewels.aspx)

If you want to only check the validity of the SQL code that you have - this might be a nice way to go, and it doesn't require SQL Server per se to be installed where you run your unit tests.

Comment: Is this parser able to verify compliance with syntax versions and availability of built-in objects and functions? This might be a blind spot.

Comment: @usr: the article does show that there is indeed a property `SqlVersion` which allows you to specify the desired version of T-SQL to be checked against.

Comment: Good to know. Still this method does not guarantee that the code works. I think it is more of a superficial syntax check. Dependencies might still fail to bind.

Comment: this statement is going wrong is sql server 2005 (but words in sql server 2008)
--------------------------------------                    
INSERT [TABEL1] ( column1, column2)
Values( @value1, (select isnull(max(column2)+1,1) from [TABEL1]))
--------------------------------------                        
I want to validate that this query fails for sql server 2005